# Grid.ColumnSpan on C# by programability

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

How could I set the Grid.ColumnSpan on C# by programability?

This is my code:

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!--B1 -->
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <!--B2 -->
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <!--B3 -->
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <!--B4 -->
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <!--B1 -->
    <dxe:SimpleButton x:Name="btn_1" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <!--B2 -->
    <dxe:SimpleButton x:Name="btn_2" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <!--B3 -->
    <dxe:SimpleButton x:Name="btn_3" Grid.Column="2"/>
    <!--B4 -->
    <dxe:SimpleButton x:Name="btn_4" Grid.Column="3"/>
</Grid>
```

I would like to set `Grid.ColumnSpan = 2` on my secound column if a conditional is true.

```
if(conditional){
    btn_2.Grid.ColumnSpan = 2;
}
```

SOLUTION:

```
if(conditional){
    btn_2.SetValue(Grid.ColumnSpanProperty, 2);
}
```

Comment: `Grid.SetColumnSpan(element, value)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the anwer [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/442de810-82c2-4389-aaf2-9f1b03877360/programmatically-change-gridcolumnspan?forum=wpf) this is the solution:

```
btn_2.SetValue(Grid.ColumnSpanProperty, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use
`Grid.SetColumnSpan(control, 2);`

Documentation here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.grid.setcolumnspan?view=net-5.0

It is an attached property and not a dependecy property (similarly as e.g. Grid.Row/Grid.Column).